# Syntax highlighting in .net richtextbox, how do I deal with newlines?

Tags: .net, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to highlight some syntax in a richtextcontrol (quoted text, XML tags, XML comments). Apart from the obvious problem created by my own stupidity (for example, a run through the text to highlight the syntax takes over a second and I certainly cannot check the syntax whenever a character was typed) I also ran into an issue caused by newlines in the text.

This is my feeble attempt to syntaxhighlight:

```
    While i < l

        ssRelevantText = t.Text.Substring(i)

        ssSelectedText = Regex.Match(ssRelevantText, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
        idxSelectionStart = t.Find(ssSelectedText, i, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
        idxSelectionLength = ssSelectedText.Length
        t.SelectionStart = idxSelectionStart
        t.SelectionLength = idxSelectionLength
        t.SelectionColor = color

        i = idxSelectionStart + idxSelectionLength
        t.SelectionStart = idxCursorBeforeSelection
        t.SelectionLength = 0
        t.SelectionColor = color.Black

    End While
```

(I removed comments because, ironically, VB comments break SO's syntax-highlighting.)

I also tried other RegexOptions but the problem remains that while, for example

"hello"

is found and accurately coloured,

"

hello

"

is not found. (The colouring also fails below such an incident, but not always.)

If I replace all newlines with some other symbol, the above works and everything is highlighted correctly. Why are newlines interfering?

Alternatively, how does one do syntax-highlighting in a richtextbox? All the examples I can find refer to syntax-highlighting of reserved words and not terms based on patterns.

Edit: I so far figured out that the RichTextBox method Find() does not find strings containing newlines. Since that triggers an exception (easily avoided) no further highlighting is done after that. How can I find a string in a RichTextBox that contains newlines?

Comment: I am now thinking that I could do this line by line if I change the patterns to work with random-length beginnings and random-length endings.

Comment: What happened to the other answer???

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2006/12/14/RichTextBox-syntax-highlighting.aspx

It provides a nice example of how to Syntax higlight in C# using a RichTextBox.

Comment: That's one of those examples I was talking about. It only explains highlighting specific words, which is not the issue here. I need to highlight syntax elements as well, i.e. "hello" and "world" should both be highlighted as quoted text, even if they contain newlines.

Comment: Are you capturing everything between quotes as 1 string? Even on a new line so when you pass the string to the regular expression it will read as. " hello "

If this is the case then before you pass the string to the regex you can do a 

String.TrimEnd('\n');

Comment: Not the problem. Spaces are not an issue. The problem is that the text I have to, say, paint red can contain newlines, like "hello\nworld". Any line-based approach would not see the end of the quoted text (and the second "). My code works for input without newlines.